# Date column shifts and is no longer callable

Tags: pandas, date, sorting

I am using pandas groupby to group duplicate dates by their pm25 values to get one average. However when I use the groupby function, the structure of my dataframe changes, and I can no longer call the 'Date' Column.

Using groupby also changes the structure of my data: instead of being sorted by 1/1/19, 1/2/19, it is sorted by 1/1/19, 1/10/19, 1/11/19.

Here is my current code:

Before using df.groupby my df looks like:

[df before groupy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4XUU.png)

I use groupby:

```
df.groupby('Date').mean('pm25')
print(df)
```

[df after groupby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxo6E.png)

And after, I cannot call the 'Date' column anymore or sort the column

```
print(df['Date'])
```

Returns just

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Please help, or please let me know what else I can provide.

Comment: the date is now the index, so df.index or use df.reset_index(), then df['Date'] should work

Comment: Just use `.reset_index()` to df.groupby() line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using groupby also changes the structure of my data: instead of being sorted by 1/1/19, 1/2/19, it is sorted by 1/1/19, 1/10/19, 1/11/19.

This is because your `Date` column type is string not datetime. In string comparison, the third character `1` of `1/10/19` is smaller than the third character `2` of `1/2/19`. If you want to keep the original sequence, you can to the following

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])          # Convert Date column to datetime type
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')  # Convert datetime to other formats (but the dtype of column will be string)
```

> And after, I cannot call the 'Date' column anymore or sort the column

This is because after groupby `Date` column, the returned dataframe will use `Date` column after groupby as index to represent each group.

```
          pm25
Date
01/01/19  8.50
01/02/19  9.20
01/03/19  7.90
01/04/19  8.90
01/05/19  6.00
```

After doing `df.groupby('Date').mean('pm25')`, the returned dataframe above means the mean `pm25` value of `01/01/19` group is 8.50, etc.

If you want to retrieve the `Date` column back from the index, you can `reset_index()` after groupby,

```py
df.groupby('Date').mean('pm25').reset_index()
```

which gives

```
       Date  pm25
0  01/01/19  8.50
1  01/02/19  9.20
2  01/03/19  7.90
3  01/04/19  8.90
4  01/05/19  6.00
5  01/06/19  6.75
6  01/11/19  8.50
7  01/12/19  9.20
8  01/21/19  9.20
```

Or specify the `as_index` argument of [pandas.DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to `False`

```py
df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).mean('pm25')
```